# Why we need distributed lock in the Redis

Tags: java, multithreading, redis, locking, distributed

Sorry for that I am the newbie for Distributed Lock and Redis, I heard about Redis is a single-threaded server. So My question is Why we need [distributed lock management](http://redis.io/topics/distlock) for the Redis? For example ,The second thread(Client B initiated) will not interrupt the previous thread until the operation of the first thread(Client A initiated) is accomplished. Even both threads are working on the same data. I knew I must miss somthing . Please kindly help to correct me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that distributed lock is not about the Redis itself (you shouldn't really care whether its single-threaded or not), but rather about your application.

It's clear what a "regular" (not distributed) lock does, but it works with multi-threaded application in the single JVM.

The word "distributed" adds a way to synchronize the access to some resource across many JVMs so that only one JVM will execute a critical section.

Now, as stated in the article you refer, its possible to implement the lock with "SET" command but the fundamental issue with such an implementation is a single point of failure of the Redis itself, that's why they're talking about the Redlock algorithm which supports to acquire a lock based on the state of many independent Redis machines. Note that in any point of this we don't really care whether the Redis itself is single- or multi-threaded.

Comment: ah...As the article put. `Distributed locks are a very useful primitive in many environments where different processes must operate with shared resources in a mutually exclusive way.` . It indeed mentioned `Multiple processes` . not just `Multiple threads`.

Comment: Exactly. Here is an example of why you can need a DL: Say, you have some analytics db. And say you want to create a report which works with that db and you know that if 2 users try to create a report simultaneously, bad things will happen. Now, since your app is running in the cluster, you need to guarantee that only one report will be created at a time, no matter on which machine (you guard the db). So the Distributed Lock can help here.

Comment: What does the single instance means in the part of `Correct implementation with a single instance` ? Does it mean the case `Master-slave` failover pattern? Thanks.

Comment: I guess, single instance means that you have only one redis server. I don't think its about master-slave, because you work only with master in any case and the slave gets synched from master. But if so, when the master goes down, it can screw up the log, hence there is a Redlock Algorithm